# oracle full join ambiguous column

Tags: oracle, join

it's very confusing

i made up 3 queries like this:

```
select 1 id from dual  ---- this is f1
select 2 id from dual ----- this is f2
select 3 id from dual ----- this is f3
```

then tried to join them together

when i did a query like

`select count(id) from f1 full join f2 on f1.id=f2.id  ==== error` because of ambiguous column id

but the below query works

```
select count(id) from f1 
full join f2 on f1.id=f2.id 
full join f3 on f1.id=f2.id or f2.id=f3.id
```

then the below query won't work because of the ambiguous column id

```
select count(id) from f1 
full join f2 on f1.id=f2.id 
full join f3 on f1.id=f2.id
```

can any one tell why the "or f2.id=f3.id" will not cause the ambiguous column id error?

Comment: For the record, your last query *does* work.

Comment: Is this a typo? `...full join f3 on f1.id=f2.id`

Comment: i just don't have the exact query, it's something like this

Comment: yes, it's a typo , it's f3 and f2 or f3 and f2

Answer (score 1):

The error is in `COUNT(ID)`, there is the table alias missing.

Comment: but when you use "or f2.id=f3.id" then there is no such error

Comment: @user999377 it looks like optimization bug, just use the alias

Comment: but when i tried the query , to select * from those, not select count(id) from those, i can see only one id column is shown, and if only one id , why we need to specify the f1.id or f2.id when count(id)?

Comment: @user999377 I know, I tried in sqlfiddle yesterday. But you should get all 3 columns. Congratulations, you have found an Oracle bug!